# HTML CSS Styling box

Tags: html, css, styles

I'm trying to format a box to look like a "status update" like feature.
Currently, this is what it looks like.
[image]

Ideally, I would like the top right hand corner of the box to display the date and the bottom right hand corner to display "Replies". As you can see from the picture, it doesn't really do this. 
Any help on how to do this is greatly appreciated.

My CSS code is here.
http://jsfiddle.net/hKcmu/

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add

```
position: relative;
```

to your containing div then use

```
boxytest sup
{
    position: absolute;
    right: 2px;
    top: 2px;
}

boxytest sub
{
    position: absolute;
    right: 2px;
    bottom: 2px;
}
```

to position the date/replies.

Heres your updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DampSquid/hKcmu/1/)

**Edit**

You can use padding on the boxytest to cope with the text being too long,

this puts enough space above and below the text for the date/replies

```
boxytest
  {
    position: relative;
    .....
    padding: 20px 0;
  }
```

and this makes room on the right

```
boxytest
  {
    position: relative;
    .....
    padding: 20px 0;
    padding: 4px 120px 4px 0;
  }
```

updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DampSquid/hKcmu/6/)

Comment: Thanks. I updated the fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/hKcmu/4/

If the message is too long, it sort of overrides the replies/date. Is there a way to make it not do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use a combination of `position: relative` and `position: absolute`:

```
boxytest {
    /* all the other CSS */
    position: relative;
}

boxytest sup {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 48%;
}
boxytest sub {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 48%;
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/hKcmu/2/).

Comment: Thanks! However, if I make the second box contain the replies/date, due to the longer text, it 'overrides' the replies/date.

http://jsfiddle.net/hKcmu/5/

Any way to rectify this?